# Wondering whether is it application of Mean Value Theorem?

Tags: calculus

> Let $f : [a,b] \to R $ be a differentiable function such that $f(x)\neq0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. Then find the value of $\frac{f'(c)}{f(c)}$ for some $c\in(a,b)$

**My attempt**

I used from Mean Value Theorem which gives for some $c\in(a,b)$
$$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$
or $$\frac{f'(c)}{f(b)-f(a)}=\frac{1}{b-a}$$Can we consider $f(b)-f(a)=f(c)$? If so, what will be the value of $a$ and $b$ in terms of $c$?
I may be wrong. I will be happy if someone can point out it.

Comment: Find the value $\frac{f'(c)}{f(c)}$ in terms of what ???  Else $\frac{f'(c)}{f(c)}$ is $\frac{f'(\frac{a+b}{2})}{f(\frac{a+b}{2})}$ for $c = \frac{a+b}{2}$.  Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f(x)\ne 0$ for all $x$ we have $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ or $f(x)<0$ for all $x$.

Say $f(x)>0$ for all $x$. Probably you should look at the function $g(x) =\ln f(x)$ and use here MVT whatever you want to do.

By MVT there is a $c\in (a,b)$ such that $$g'(c) = {g(b)-g(a)\over b-a}$$ so

$${f'(c)\over f(c)} = {1\over b-a}\ln {f(b)\over f(a)}$$

Comment: Actually there are four options for the answer-1)$\frac{1}{a+b}$ 2) $\frac{1}{b+c}$ 3)$\frac{1}{a-c}$ 4)$\frac{1}{a-c}$+$\frac{1}{b-c}$. I am not still sure whether taking $lnf(x)$ will do the work or not.

Comment: Thank you very much Christian. It is quite clear now.